# Determine all solutions of the congruence $4 953^m \cdot n \equiv 13 383 \pmod{14 553}$ in integers $m,n$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Determine all solutions of the congruence $4 953^m \cdot n \equiv 13 383 \pmod{14 553}$ in integers $m,n$.

Hi everyone, I need some help with this one. I saw another thread that solved $12^x \equiv 17 \pmod{ 25}$, however I do not know how to retrace the steps when I also have an integer $n$. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Geez, what sadist makes up these questions?  What point can possible be learned here that couldn't be learned with more reasonable composed integers?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint;* The congruence needs to hold mod $\gcd(13383,14553)=9$.

Comment: Ok, so with 14 553 = 3^3 * 7^2 * 11 I get:
4 953^m * n ≡ 18 (mod 27)
4 953^m * n ≡ 6 (mod 49)
4 953^m * n ≡ 7 (mod 11).
From here I have two thoughts;
1) @lhf says that gcd(13 383, 14 553) = 9 must hold, well
    gcd(18, 27) = 9, gcd(6,49) = 1 and gcd(7, 11) = 1. Should that mean 
    something to me?
2) Can I seperate 4 953^m * n as:
    4 953^m ≡ 18 (mod 27) <-> 12^m ≡ 18 (mod 27) and n ≡ 18 (mod 27)
    4 953^m ≡ 6 (mod 49) <-> 4^m ≡ 6 (mod 49) and n ≡ 6 (mod 49)
    4 953^m ≡ 7 (mod 11) <-> 3^m ≡ 7 (mod 11) and n ≡ 7 (mod 11)
    and solve them seperatly?

Comment: Jesus, that's messy. I'm sorry for the layout (looked different when I wrote it), but som help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of general advice: modular equations modulo a composite number can generally be simplified by looking at its prime power factors. In this case, $14553 = 3^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11$, so an equation $A \equiv B \pmod{14453}$ is equivalent to the system of equations
\begin{align}
  A &\equiv B \pmod{3^3} \\
  A &\equiv B \pmod{7^2} \\
  A &\equiv B \pmod{11}
\end{align}
(This is justified by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.)

For complicated equations, this might not solve the problem for you, but it's a good first step no matter what you're doing. (And in this case, one of the three equations narrows down your possibilities to only three values of $m$...)